# PHP if statements for numbers/digits greater than/less than

Tags: php, math, preg-replace, preg-match, digits

I have a little puzzle I'm trying to solve with no joy yet. I want to have a set of ifelse statements filter a number variable. Sort of like this.

If the assets are greater than 1500000, make the value down to a 6 digit number maximum using the numbers existing.

If the assets is smaller than 599999, make the value up to a 6 digit maximum using the numbers existing.

If the assets is between 599999 and 1500000, leave the variable alone and let it pass.

```
if ($assets > 1500000) {
  $assets_calc = preg_match_all('/(\d{6})/', $assets_array, $matches);
} 
elseif ($assets < 599999) {
  $assets_calc = preg_match_all('/someregex here/', $assets_array, $matches);           
} else {            
  $assets = $assets          
}
```

Not sure if that is possible.

Comment: assets?? what kind of assets? Is `$assets` an array, a string, an integer?

Comment: Can you show us an example? Is the value is 1500001 - what number do you want to get? And if it's 599998?

Comment: @w0rldart - it's obvious he means the `$assets` variable from the code. And since he's comparing it to numbers, it has to be a number (or a string with a number, doesn't matter for PHP).

Comment: you want get the string result or int result

Comment: The $assets is a string i pulled from a CSV file. Sorry i was'nt clear enough. If the string is less than 6 digits i want to add adigit to it making it a 6 digit number again. If the number is more than 6 digits i want to removw a digit making it 6.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answers your question but are you looking to simply truncate digits of each value in the array?

```
if ($assets > 1500000)
{
    foreach($assets_array as $k=>$v)
    {
        $assets_calc[$k] = (int)substr((string)$v, 0, 6);
    }
}
// implement substring() in rest of code here
```